# Why is current not charge/area?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, charge, dimensional-analysis

Current is defined as charge/time and the only use of current is to see how much charge passes through an area in 1 second, and current depends on voltage.

So even if we change current as charge/area or charge/volume it shouldn't be wrong, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quantity that you are thinking of is called current density. It is charge per area per time (you were forgetting the time).

Current and current density have different purposes. Current is more useful for circuit theory and current density is more useful for Maxwell’s equations. In circuit theory we use a lumped element approximation which eliminates all of the geometry of the circuit. So you do not want to add a quantity like current density which requires geometrical knowledge. On the other hand, current density is one of the sources in Maxwell’s equations so you cannot avoid it there. You need to use each one where it is appropriate